# What is the jscript mistake in VS2012 Project?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, visual-studio-2012

this is my script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post", dataType: "json", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://localhost:63384/ListWebService.asmx/Helloworld", success: function (data) { alert(data.d); }, error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

In the Hello World i am returning "Hello World". i am getting output correct in vs 2010 project but in VS 2012 Project the same code produces alert box with "undefined" as output.

Comment: Use your broseer debug tools (F12 on most browsers) to see what is actually being returned by the ajax call. That will show you the problem I'll bet

Answer (score 1):

when you give you url you don't have the need to give complete path just simply write ListWebService.aspx/Helloworld.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have jQuery included? Check with fiddler or dev tools (F12) if the call to the aspx actually happens...
Post us code demo so we can debug....

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it seems u r not posting any data but rather only fetching data from webservice. Whats wrong with 'GET' request?

use a debugging tool firebug to find what response u r getting back.

example [image]

use breakpoint inside ur success method to break into the code and find what is being held in the 'data'.

*learn to use debugging tools (f12) it will save your time and even may be a little bit of  your hairs...lol :P*